# Locally importing, editing, and debugging Lambda Functions with the AWS Toolkit for Cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloud9

AWS Cloud9 is making an update to its UI. They removed a tab called "AWS Resources" which allowed you to import and upload changes to your lambda functions. It also would create a

When enabled, AWS Toolkit replaces the AWS Resources window for working with Lambda functions and serverless apps. On January 31, 2021, 00:00 (UTC+0:00), AWS Toolkit will fully replace the AWS Resources panel. When toggled, your browser refreshes to update the IDE's interface.

The main reason I use cloud9 is that I can write, edit, and actually have live debugging sessions. Lambda with Cloud9 really accelerates the development of Lambda functions. Losing this feature, honestly makes me feel that we are taking a step back in terms of ease of use.

Things I am struggling with right now are debugging the lambda locally on Cloud9. Usually, Cloud9 would spin up a template.YAML file, but now this is no longer the case.

Looking for help on making this transition, thank you in advance!

Comment: Having the same issue. So far the best solution that I've found is to use the python serverlless library.